# SSMS updates issue

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I recently installed new version of SSMS (18.3.1). The issue is it can not connect to SSIS. In other words, SSIS can not be opened by SSMS.

I’m using SQL Server 2016 SP2 CU10.

I also received the answer that I need to use same version of SSMS that matches with SSIS version but it doesn't make sense. SSIS version gets updated with SQL Server updates and I have the latest one.

Comment: From my experience, SSMS is backwards compatible with all SQL Server versions. It is *NOT* backwards compatible with SSIS, SSAS, SSRS, etc. Try with the version that comes with your install.

Comment: What does SSMS have to do with SSIS?

Comment: @dfundako Which IDE do you use to connect to SSIS?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-ver15

•Additionally, SSMS 18.x can be installed side by side with SSMS 17.x, SSMS 16.x, or SQL Server 2014 SSMS and earlier.

Comment: opening SSIS from management studio,  connecting to SSIS packages. I am fine with version 16.   but need to use new version

Comment: Yes, as everyone (including myself) is telling you, that will not work. You can ask the question a third time, and get the same answer a third time, or you can accept this and find a workaround... or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Jacob H, I will post your answer here. and check as answered:

**SSMS is backwards compatible with all SQL Server versions. It is NOT backwards compatible with SSIS, SSAS, SSRS**